# File system hierarchy representation

Tags: files, directory

The question is perhaps trivial, but I was wondering about the existence of a command to `print` the current file hierarchy of my machine. For example:

```
printhierarchy

root/bin 
    /boot
    /dev
    /etc/opt
        /sgml
        /X11/xsub1
             xsub2/xsubb2
        /X12/...
    /home/...
```

I would appreciate such a representation for didactic purposes, mainly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `tree`, and specifically `tree -d /`:

```
/
├── bin
├── boot
│   ├── efi
│   │   └── EFI
│   │       └── debian
│   │           └── fw
│   ├── floppies
│   ├── grml
│   ├── grub
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── i386-pc
│   │   └── locale
│   └── lost+found
├── crypthome
├── dev
│   ├── block
│   ├── bsg
│   ├── bus
│   │   └── usb
│   │       ├── 001
│   │       ├── 002
│   │       ├── 003
│   │       ├── 004
│   │       ├── 005
│   │       └── 006
│   ├── char
```

etc.

Comment: It works perfectly. I was looking exactly for something like that. Thank you Stephen!